Increase player jump height depending on how long they hold the jump button
I need some help making my final project in java, a game.
Here is the code I have now for jumping:
if (Keys.up) {
    if (player[1] + player[3] >= base[1]) {
        player[5] = -20;
    }
}

This code makes the player y velocity (player[5] in the array) -20 (upwards in my case) if the player y position (player[1]) plus the player height (player[3]) is greater (or equal to) the ground y position (base[1]), or in other words, is touching the base (ground).
This code runs every frame.
How could I modify this to have the player jump height change base on how long you hold the up arrow key, instead of always being a set value of -20?
I tried making a variable for frames but couldn't figure it out.

You could use a Swing Timer.

if (player[1] + player[3] >= base[1]) { player[5] += -5; }?
